# Java - Clone the property inside getter method

Tags: java, coding-style, clone, getter-setter

Folks,

I was going through Java's best coding practises mentioned here
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/most-useful-java-best-practice-quotes-java-developers/

2nd quote says,

> Quote 2: Never make an instance fields of class public

I agree that's absolutely correct, but I got stuck for following writer's recommendation few lines below this quote.

He says,

---

```
private String[] weekdays = 
    {"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"};

public String[] getWeekdays() {
    return weekdays;
}
```

But writing getter method does not exactly solve our problem. The array is still accessible. Best way to make it unmodifiable is to return a clone of array instead of array itself. Thus the getter method will be changed to

```
public String[] getWeekdays() {
    return weekdays.clone();
}
```

---

I have never myself used `clone()` inside any getter method of Java class.

I am wondering ( ***as it is mentioned to be one of the good practises*** ) - why one `should use` / `shouldn't use` `clone()` inside getter method ? and in which scenarios ?

Does it qualify to be a good coding practise for Java ?

Thanks

Comment: IMO - For immutable objects and primitive data types clone is not required. For everything else if we really want our data to be safe we must return the clone copy and not the original.

Comment: You could return `Arrays.asList(weekdays)`, which will be immutable.

Comment: @Jivings not true. The List won't accept new elements, but the set() methods work.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd: Yes, quite right. You can still use `set`, just not change the size. My mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is discussed in the book **"Effective Java"** by *Joshua Bloch*. There's a section called *"Make defensive copies when needed"* (Section 39 in 2nd edition).

https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31551&seqNum=2

A good book to dwell on topics like this.

Answer (score 3):

```
private String[] weekdays =      
    {"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"};  

public String[] getWeekdays() 
{     
    return weekdays; 
}
```

If you don't use `clone` method, the user of this class can do a lot of unethical things:

1. change the order of days,
2. change the name of days,
3. ...

But, returning a clone won't affect the class and it's data. So, other users of class won't be affected.

Comment: But I didn't see that clone() method recommendation on any website before. I didn't see most of the programmers (even some java geeks)  use that in their examples. I doubt, if that's a good coding practise then ? :O

Comment: @bomslang A lot will come down your requirements. As Azodious has pointed out, not cloning (proving any other copy of the data) can lead to unexpected problems for your class, but you need to decide if this is the behavior you want. The reason you probably don't see it is because it's more typing for most people. If you have a look in the Swing API, you see a lot of simular practices, when return `Dimension`, the class will often create a new `Dimension` object, using it's internal reference as the seed of that new class, essentially, cloning it.

Comment: Yes, it is. and personally i've used it in a case almost similar to your example. But it should not be used blindly cause if a heavy object is cloned, it'll lead to memory issues. So, clone only that data which a user shouldn't modify.

Comment: @All : Does it qualify under good coding practises to follow in java ?

Comment: @bomslang: Any good practice is considered good for most of the real-time scenerios (not always). However if cloning is considered a good practice, it'll be for much lesser scenerios. It all depends on your design also. If you don't want to use `clone()`, you can use some other strategies suggested here: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=71

Answer (score 2):

You `clone() or System.arraycopy()` on `get()` if you want guarantee that the whole object graph (that contains the array) is immutable. This is done usually when the API that exposes the array is *public* and there are constraints on the values in the array or when the objects are accessed by multiple threads. In such cases the immutability is important.

Let say, you have a `GroceryStore` object that has `getItemsSortedByPrice()` method. You keep the items in array that maintains the order by price, but if you return this array, the client code can possibly modify it and break the (internal) invariants of your object.

If this is internal code (i.e.) not part of the public API, and you know that you wont modify the array, then cloning/coping probably is not necessary as it hurts performance without real benefit.

All depends on the context.

Arrays are just objects, and all (im)mutability rules/practices that apply to an ordinary object, apply to arrays too.

Comment: +1 for System.arrayCopy(), although I'd recommend the more usable version Arrays.copyOf() (which of course uses System.arrayCopy() internally)

Answer (score 1):

I think your usecase is not matching the proposed Java code. The example is for a different usecase than yours.

A final array sounds to me like [Enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) and i think this is matching your requirement much better.